# Which UI treament of a large photo is more successful?

Tags: css

I am about to launch a beer app on Facebook, and while it's a minor detail, I am deciding between two ways to display the photo:

**Option 1:**

> [image: same padding]
>   http://cl.ly/082D0I3A1u0S0W0S1x2w

Padding is less than the body text, but a little edge remains so it's clear that this is all one post. The advantage of this may be the variety it creates, and the nice large size for a photo?

**Option 2:**

> [image: less padding than surrounding elements]
>   http://cl.ly/3R0M261p2Z2V0x0F211b

Padding is the same on the photo as the rest of the content, resulting in more breathing room between each post in the feed.

Comment: #2 feels better.

Answer (score 3):

My instinctive response is to keep the padding consistent, just on aesthetics.

This could partly be explained by the [closure gestalt principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping) as well as the proximity principle .. having the edges out of alignment makes the images appear further away.

Also, consider how the eye may track down the page - with the ragged edge presented by the bulging images there is no smooth direct line, instead the eye has to bump out and bump back in again.

Comment: Those extra 10 pixels aren't adding much to the image--and people will zoom in anyway if they want more detail. Keep your edges clean and even and it'll feel more polished.

Comment: I go with aesthetics (+1). Also, because your background is not solid, the equal padding makes the images clearer (for me).

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to @Erics, my instinctive response is to use the smaller margins. While I understand the reasons for consistency, I think the requirement here is to show the photo as large as can be managed, to give the best possible detail.

I don;t think you lose the connectivity, but what it does do, for me, is extend the scope of the printed text to include some white space at the start - so the margin line continues from the photo down.

The larger margins look to me like wasting space. It is like having thicker glass on the beer glasses - it may make them stronger, but I want the content, not the glass.